# Adding a "." to the name of a Workbook without changing its format in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format

Just began coding in VBA so this might be a basic question. My script saves a workbook with a concatenated name. However, within the concatenation I must add a ".", VBA thinks I am referring to the format of the newly saved file when I am still editing its name. The result is a saved file that can't be run because no program identifies the format.

Any thoughts on this?

```
Sub Save_New_File ()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim CarModel As String
Dim Month As Integer

CarModel = "Corolla"
Month = 10

wb1.SaveAs Filename:=CarModel+"."+Month

End Sub
```

Comment: Include the extension?

Comment: Something like: `wb1.SaveAs Filename:=CarModel & "." & Month & ".xlsm"`

Comment: You should *always* specify the `FileFormat` argument for `SaveAs`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the format extension at the end of the string fixed the issue. I did not add it the first time thinking VBA would save the file using the same format of the Workbook I was moving the specific sheet out of (what I referred to as "file"). I will add the extension at the end as well as the FileFormat parameter to be sure.

Thank you,